# Remove first line in JSON response

Tags: objective-c, json, string, newline

I am using the Google Speech API unofficially. If you send it an audio file saying "Test", it will respond with this:

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"test","confidence":0.88845605},{"transcript":"tests"},{"transcript":"the test"},{"transcript":"text"},{"transcript":"Test"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

I need to remove the first line of this response so my parser will not error out.

Is there an official way to remove this first line in the JSON?

I am using Xcode 6.1 (I haven't updated Xcode yet) with the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Comment: Could you give more information on the context of the file? Is it a text file? Will there always be two lines of information? Are they separated on two different lines? I take it you just want to obtain the email from this file in question?

Comment: @DanielStorm Yes. It's actually a JSON file, but my parser gives me something like this. They are seperated on different lines. It's stored in a NSString. There will always be 2 lines. And yes, I'm trying to get the email.

Comment: @Rob Ok. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Hmm. That's not a valid JSON response. That looks like two JSON responses. Or perhaps you had an array that wrapped these two dictionaries that you've cut out of the question. Maybe we have to go back one more step and show us how you got this response. I'd be surprised if the Google speech API actually returned this...

Comment: @Rob My project is a copy of https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text . It works for them, but not for me, apparently.

Comment: Can you not get hold of the person who creates that JSON response and tell them to fix it? It really isn't up to you to mess around with the JSON after you receive it.

Comment: @Rob I got it working using Daniel Storm's answer. Thank you for attempting to help me! I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: @Fogmeister I would, but I'm using the API unofficially. (It's not really documented anywhere, except its usage in Chromium)

Comment: The proposed work-around extracts what you need from incorrect output, but IMHO you should understand _why_ you got the output you did and then address that root problem. But given the complexity of it, I completely understand why the simple string manipulation/parsing approach is so appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assuming your string looks something like this
NSString *fileContents = @"Bob Smith: 1 (234)-567-8901\nBob Smith: bob@bob.com";
// Lets store the information on each new line in an array
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
// The second object will contain the email
NSString *email = [lines objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@",email);
```

Comment: Hi, I had to edit my question. Please read the new one. Thank you for answering the original one though!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


NSArray* allLinedStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
         [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

In this array you can judge if it contains a phoneNumber, `str` is every element.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][1];
```

if phoneNumber is a phoneNumber format. Then delete this line.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I agree; but I don't always know what the first line will be. It could be `Sherly Smith: 1 (475)-555-7745`.

Comment: I had to edit my question. Please see the new question.

Comment: You question is still not very clear, its like test.json file? But it seems not a very normal json format(You example should be in a {} or [], array or dictionary). But if json file it's easy to convert it into NSDictionary, then use removeObjectForKey method to make it.

Comment: @WilliamHu It's what Google Speech gives me. I have no idea why, but it does.

Comment: I have no idea about what do you mean. If the answer you choose works well, you might should try the method i provide.  But anyway you solved the issue.